# how do I make CSV Uploader select certain values if CSV file is put in different order

Tags: php, csv

I am currently working on an CSV Uploader project and I have it working correctly but my question is - How would I make it select (firstname, lastname, email, phone, etc) if clients CSV file is put together differently.  Or would the client who is uploading the file have to have it in the order the program is made?

Here is php code ----------------------------------------------

```
try {  
  # MySQL with PDO_MYSQL  
  $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);  
  $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

}  
catch(PDOException $e) { 
    echo "I'm sorry, I'm afraid I can't do that.";  
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);   
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $file = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'];   

    $handle = fopen($file , "r");

    while (($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) !== false)
    {
        $firstname = $fileop[0];
        $lastname = $fileop[1];
        $email = $fileop[2];
        $phone = $fileop[3];

        $insertdata = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO csv (firtname, lastname, email, phone) VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$email','$phone')");
        $insertdata->execute();
    }
    if ($insetdata){
        echo "Successfully Uploaded. Thank you.";   
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time!

UPDATED----------------------------------------------

New code

```
   try {  
      # MySQL with PDO_MYSQL  
      $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);  
      $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    }  
    catch(PDOException $e) { 
        echo "I'm sorry, I'm afraid I can't do that.";  
        file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);   
    }

    function returnBack(){

        header("Location:http://pcgprotects.com/PCG/csvuploader/csvuploaderform.php?seterror=1");
        exit;

    }

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

        /*******************************GET NAME OF COLUMNS IN CSV FILE *********************************************************/
        if (empty($_POST['files'])){
            returnBack();
        }
        if (empty($_POST['firstname'])){
            returnBack();
        }
        if (empty($_POST['lastname'])){
            returnBack();
        }if (empty($_POST['email'])){
            returnBack();
        }
        if (empty($_POST['phone'])){
            returnBack();
        }
$file = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'];   

        $handle = fopen($file , "r");
        $fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",");
        $firstname_index = array_search($_POST['firstname'],$fileop);
        if (empty($firstname_index)){
            returnBack();
        }
        $lastname_index = array_search($_POST['lastname'],$fileop);
        if (empty($lastname_index)){
            returnBack();
        }
        $email_index = array_search($_POST['email'],$fileop);
        if (empty($email_index)){
            returnBack();
        }
        $phone_index = array_search($_POST['phone'],$fileop);
        if (empty($phone_index)){
            returnBack();
        }

        /***********************ASSIGN COLUMN VALUES TO ACCORDING VARIABLES AND INSERT THEN INTO CSV TABLE IN DB *************************************/


        while (($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) !== false)
        {
            $firstname = $fileop[$firstname_index];
            $lastname = $fileop[$lastname_index];
            $email = $fileop[$email_index];
            $phone = $fileop[$phone_index];

            $insertdata = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO csv (firtname, lastname, email, phone) VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$email','$phone')");
            $insertdata->execute();
        }
        if ($insetdata){
            echo "Successfully Uploaded. Thank you.";   
        }
    }
```

In my csv trial file i used columns named - First name, Last name, Phone, Email.  Then in my form I entered those values but I got kicked back - here is my Form code -----

```
    <table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form method="post" action="csvuploader.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>CSV Uploader </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Enter Name of First Name Column </td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="fisrtname" type="text" ><?php 
    $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
    if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>Need Exact Name</span>";
    }
        ?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Enter Name of Last Name Column </td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="lastname" type="text" ><?php 
    $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
    if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>Need Exact Name</span>";
    }
        ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Enter Name of Email Column </td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="email" type="text" ><?php 
    $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
    if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>Need Exact Name</span>";
    }
        ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Enter Name of Phone Number Column </td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="phone" type="text" ><?php 
    $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
    if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>Need Exact Name</span>";
    }
        ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="294"><input type="file" name="files" /><?php 
    $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
    if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>Select a File</span>";
    }
        ?></td>
</tr>
<br />
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ask the customer to add one line in the beginning of the CSV that will show the structure, for example:

```
firstname,lastname,email,phone
joe,smith,j@gmail.com,41595648855
joe2,smith2,j2@gmail.com,41595648852
```

...

from reading the first line - you'll be able to know which token you should use with which index.

```
$file = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'];   
$handle = fopen($file , "r");
$fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",");
$firstname_index = array_search("firstname",$fileop);
$lastname_index = array_search("lastname",$fileop);
...
//and then
while (($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) !== false)
{
  $firstname = $fileop[$firstname_index];
  $lastname = $fileop[$lastname_index];
  ...
```

Comment: Oh so in the form section have a table for them to put the order of the csv file correct?

Comment: @DavidBiga exactly! I added some example code that will be more self-explanatory

Comment: so with the above code I would just need to tell them to make there column that has all the first names, etc. To have it called firstname correct?

Comment: yes, the first line shows the order in which they input the fields in the rest of the CSV, after you know the order, you can continue and read all the data.

Comment: as long as `$firstname_index = array_search("firstname",$fileop);
$lastname_index = array_search("lastname",$fileop);` is there and and anywhere in their CSV file they have column named firstname and column named lastname it will pick it up than I can assign the values to variables and ass them to db according to db setup correct?

Comment: yes. you can test it on an example CSV pretty easily. try to change the order of the columns and see that it works.

Comment: When I try to run it I get an error saying server error and I don't know why.

Comment: update the question with the code and the first few lines of the CSV you're using

Comment: okay nvm its working now. But I'm trying to see if it can find the names that where put in and if it cannot it will kick back so here check above.

Comment: yes, looks good. still - I would test it on a few different CSV files to make sure it handles corner-cases